# How to solve rendering problem on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I am the admin of my company's website i got some problem. I have carousel on which category page, on my computer the rendering is perfect but on others computers all the images are displayed as you can see :   [On my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrhSe.png)[Others computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wt3q.jpg)
https://galit.co.il/%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%9d/

The problem is that i don't know how to solve the problem because i can't see it on my admin computer.

I tried to modify with elementor but don't know how to solve.

Comment: there seems to be an overflow:hidden missing. I am seeing the issue. Try to open it in incognito or in a different browser and see if you have some kind of cached resource on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to open the website in different browser and incognito on my collegues computer, there is still the same problem. How can i fix it ?